# How to configure monitoring for multiple IBM cloud apps at once

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, availability-monitoring, ibm-cloud-monitoring

My application consists of >10 microservices every of each is running as cloud foundry app in IBM Cloud.
They run in multiple environments (dev, test, prod, etc).
I want to add monitoring to them and now I'm only able to do this configuring every app in every environment separately (add monitoring and configure test location, interval, etc).

Is there a way to configure all of them at once, at least per environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM Cloud PaaS (Bluemix) does not really have the concept of a business application and so there is no built-in support for what you are looking for.

For Enterprise level support for this concept consider using https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/application-performance-management  which does have this support.

You can somewhat emulate this by creating a separate space (e.g. Monitoring) and a dummy application (e.g. AllMyApps -- it does not even have to be running), and create tests under that application to monitor all your routes/apps from there.  This feature is somewhat accidental and may not be supported in the future.  Alternatively, you could pick one of your existing applications and monitor all apps from there.